# Pandas - Create two columns - Simple, no?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Well hello everyone!

I want to create a (panda) dataset called df. This df panda form must contain "Id" and "Feature" columns. Any idea on how to do it?

I have done the following code but... the @@ dictionaries are messy and put in random the two columns. I want "Id" as first column and "Feature" as a second one.

Thank you in advance! Have a loooong weekend!

```
df = DataFrame({'Feature': X["Feature"],'Id': X["Id"] })
```

Comment: the problem here is that inherently the order of the keys in dict will not necessarily be the same as the order of creation, you can reorder the columns afterwards doing `df = df.ix[:, ['Id','Feature']]`

Comment: Great, many thanks!

Any idea on how to do the same with just using pandas without this two step procedure, I would be much appreciated for your assistance. It is just feature selection but still aint sure how to deal with it.

Comment: "I want "Id" as first column and "Feature" as a second one". Imo, there is no good reason to want that. Only when showing/printing your dataframe, and then you need a second step (eg `print`) anyway, where you can use EdChum's solution.

Comment: well there is actually, since I want to export that as a csv and I find it quite difficult because (the csv file), merges the two columns (Id and Feature) ~ so annoying :/... Thus I am trying to find a way to separate them (but mostly to understand how this works).

Comment: The order is irrelevant, you can index the columns using the names so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) "If no columns are passed, the columns will be the sorted list of dict keys." I do this simple trick to arrange the columns. Just add "1", "2", etc. to beginning of your column names. For example:

```
>>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,2,3],"Feature":[5,6,7]})
>>>> df1
   Feature  Id
0        5   1
1        6   2
2        7   3
>>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"1Id":[1,2,3],"2Feature":[5,6,7]})
>>>> df2
   1Id  2Feature
0    1         5
1    2         6
2    3         7
>>>> df2.columns = ["Id","Feature"]
>>>> df2
   Id  Feature
0   1        5
1   2        6
2   3        7
```

Now you have the order you wanted for printing or saving the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

If this what you wanted?

```
import pandas as pd
data=["id","Feature"]
index=[1,2]
s = pd.Series(data,index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2), index=index, columns=('id','features'))
```

The data frame :

`>>> df['id']`

```
1    0.254105
2   -0.132025
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

`>>> df['features']`

```
1    0.189972
2    2.262103
Name: features, dtype: float64
```

Comment: kinda ~ I need also the values from:

X["Id"] and X["Feature"] 

not only the data and indexes. Sorry for this misunderstanding though and thank you for your effort.